# how to delete files from SD card after uninstall my application

Tags: android

I am working on application which will create some text files into the SD card and store some data into it.

These files will be there in the SD card all the time.

Whenever user uninstall my application , I want to delete all the files in SD card which has been created by my application.

I can't clean up in onDestroy() as it will be called many times in application life cycle.

Please suggest me what I have to do to make sure my files will be get deleted without any user interaction.

I got to know that getExternalCacheDir() will do the what I need , But my files are big , I need 1GB of space from the SD card , 
can getExternalCacheDir() useful for me.?

Comment: Your Files is Created After Starting of Your Application?

Comment: yes. I am creating files in my onCreate() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `Context.getExternalFilesDir()`, from the API reference:

> "This is like getFilesDir() in that these files will be deleted when
>   the application is uninstalled"

Comment: Hi K-ballo thanks for your suggestion , but Is there any way that I can get path in "String" form. The above  Context.getExternalFilesDir is returning "file" .

Comment: How about File.getPath or any of the other getters? Remember File class actually represents a path.

Comment: K-ballo thanks again , I need some more help from you my application is having different components and I need to create/modify files from different places. So I need common file path so I am assigning file path to the constant in Interface,but Context is not available in Interface, If I hardcode it will it work..?? I am getting "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/mypackage/files" when I print the above constant.  Will this path be same in all devices..?? My app should go in all devices at least Froyo and Ginger Bread .

Comment: Hardcoding the path wont work. I have seen devices with multiple SD cards in which the path would be /mnt/sdcard/external_sd/... and thats just one example. However, you should get the same path from all activities within the same package, so as long as you have a single apk you should be able to call getExternalFilesDir once and pass that value around.

Comment: Thanks k-ballo, Which I have to use getPath() or getAbsolutePath(). Observed that both or returning same value.

Comment: Both probably will, I would go with the absolute version just to be on the safer side of the road.